# Input form fields are cannot be updated in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I'm creating simple web page which has modal for creating new object `Partner` and sending it to server. And several input fields to display newly created data. I am using Angualr10 and [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/) for the components.

I have a `button` and a `form` with only `input` fields, which are disabled and they serve the purpose of just representing created `Partner`.

After landing on page, user can click on button to open modal to enter new data about `Partner`. After hitting `"save"`, I successfully sent `Partner` object to the server and get it back with an id. After that, `currentPartner` is initialized and not null.

[image]

My problem is that I'm not able to update input fields using `currentPartner` object. How do I know that `currentPartner` is not null? Well, if I click on any of the input fields (after sending data to server), that filed is updated with data I previously entered in the modal.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    currentPartner : Partner; //declare partner

      savePartnerAndCloseModal(modal : any){
           modal.hide()
           var partner = <Partner>{}
           partner.name = this.name.value;
           partner.phone = this.phone.value;
           partner.taxNumber = this.taxNo.value;
           partner.email =  this.phone.value;
           partner.address = this.address.value;
    
           this.partnerService.addPartner(partner).subscribe(data =>{
             this.currentPartner = data //Partner from server with id
             this.partners.push(data) //some list with other Partners
           });

  }
```

```
      <form class="text-center border border-light p-5" >
      
        <p class="h4 mb-4">Business Partner</p>
      
        <!-- Name -->
        <div [ngModel]="currentPartner" *ngIf="currentPartner; else elseBlock">
          <input type="text"    mdbInput disabled
          class="form-control mb-4" [value]="currentPartner.name"  >
        </div>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <input type="text" disabled   mdbInput
          class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Name" >
        </ng-template>
        
                 
        <!-- Address -->
        <input type="text" disabled mdbInput
          class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Address">
       
        //other properties (inputs) for partner
      </form>
```

What else is the problem? I don't know "Angular" way of saying: "If `currentPartner` is null display placeholder value, else display `currentPartner`'s value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are super close, you can use `ng-template` and `ng-container` to toggle the UI based on `currentPartner`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currentPartner; else placeholderPartner">
  <!-- shows when currentPartner is defined -->
</ng-container>

<ng-template #placeholderPartner>
  <!-- shows when currentPartner is null/undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that if part is ng-container and else part is ng-template. Thanks again! I was struggling, my first web angular project as java dev...